# Collection Wise Auditing and Storing logs in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have to store the audit logs for my Mongodb. For that I have completed setting in mongod.cfg file for JSON file as output. But my concern is to get output collection wise.
I am having below syntax for creating logs in JSON file as,

```
 storage:
             dbPath: data/db
        auditLog:
            destination: file
            format: JSON
            path: data/db/auditLog.json
```

But now my concern is to get logs collectionwise.
Can anyone help me to configure logging collection wise in MongoDB.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Are you trying to query the audit logs? Store the audit logs so that they're more queryable? Include more information in the audit logs?

Comment: Actually I am looking for default auditing in mongoDB just by adding some configuration. I have setup the confiuration in mongod.cfg file for output format in JSON file. But my concern is to get audit logs collection wise. Means if I am having collection A and B. Should I get logs of A separetely and L9gs of B separately in any format like JSON or BSON. Does it possible?